# Using Intl.NumberFormat, is it possible to have three minIntegerDigits that are non-zero?

Tags: javascript, logic, currency, intl, currency-formatting

When using scientific notation, writing 1000g is the same as 1kg.

When using Intl.NumberFormat with the compact notation and currency style, it switches automatically from £999 to £1k.

When using also the property minIntegerDigits=3, I expected it to wait until having three integer digits to switch, so it would be from £99,999 to £100k.
Instead it adds leading zeros, switching from £999 to £001k.

Is it possible to achieve the following formats:

£99,999.99 then £100.00k

£9,999.99k then £10.00M

£9,999.99M then £10.00B

?
Or at least something similar.

My thought was to divide the number to get it in the integer size I need, then combine the output of formatToParts taking the "literal" from one and the "integer" and "fraction" parts from another. But it just feels too messy.
(pseudo-code, something like)

```
numericalParts = formatToParts(value/1000)
semanticalParts = formatToParts(1000)

return numericalParts.integer + numericalParts.fraction + semanticalParts.literal + semanticalParts.currency
```

Comment: The following gives the correct output: `const number = 999;  console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat([], {style :"currency", currency: "GBP", minimumIntegerDigits:3, notation:"compact"  }).format(number));`

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei but if the number is 999999, it renders £001M this is precisely my question, I'd like to get £999K instead of £001M

Comment: The method works differently. `999,000` become `999K` also `999,400` becomes `999K` but from above `999,500` it becomes `1M`, I think due to rounding. I also think the `minimumIntegerDigits` is the number of digits to display.

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei Brilliant explanation of the rounding! Thank you!

I think I found something close enough `new Intl.NumberFormat([], {style :"currency", currency: "GBP", notation:"compact", minimumSignificantDigits: 6 }).format(999999)` returns `£999.999K`.

`minimumSignificantDigits` forces to not round in this scenario, but you can't use it in combination with min or max fraction digits.

Sadly it jumps from 999K to 1M, I can't achieve 9,999.99K

Comment: Thanks. Try it without the compact mode and then apply your own code